# How to add images from a string-array of urls to an activity's scrollview linear layout dynamically

Tags: android, android-asynctask, imageview, scrollview

I have a string resource with urls to a bunch of images in the jpg format, as a string-array resource in string.xml. I am trying to add these images dynamically to the activity. I first tried just adding textviews of the links on to the activity and this worked. But when I try to actually add the images it gave me a android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException. To fix this, I added an Async Task, but this still didnt work. Please tell me what I am doing wrong. I am very new to Android programming, so please forgive me if this is a stupid question. This is the code I have so far for this:

```
package com.example.testgallery;

import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Gallery extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gallery);
        List<String> pictures = Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.gallery_2014));
        LinearLayout piclayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.gallery_preview_scroll_layout);
        for(int x=0;x<pictures.size();x++) {
            String url = pictures.get(x);
            TextView urlview = new TextView(this);
            urlview.setText(url);
            piclayout.addView(urlview);
            try {
                new getPictures().execute(url);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("Picture Error",e.toString());
            }
        }
    }

    public void addImage(InputStream is){
        Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "Picture");
        ImageView image = new ImageView(Gallery.this);
        image.setImageDrawable(d);
        LinearLayout piclayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.gallery_preview_scroll_layout);
        piclayout.addView(image);
    }

    class getPictures extends AsyncTask<String, Void, InputStream> {

        private Exception exception;

        protected InputStream doInBackground(String... urls) {
            InputStream is = null;
            for(String url : urls) {
                try {
                    is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.d("Picture Error", e.toString());
                }
            }
            return is;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(InputStream is) {
            addImage(is);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I kept trying and came up with a quick solution. This may not be the best solution, but it works:

```
package com.example.testgallety

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Gallery extends AppCompatActivity {

    List<String> urls;
    Bitmap bmImg = null;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gallery);
        urls = Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.gallery_2014));
        for(int i=0;i<urls.size();i++){
            String url;
            url = urls.get(i);
            new getPictures().execute(url);
        }
    }

    public void addImage(InputStream is){

    }

    class getPictures extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        private Exception exception;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute(){
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            InputStream is = null;
            URL uri;
            String url = args[0];
            try {
                uri = new URL(url);
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) uri.openConnection();
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                conn.connect();
                is = conn.getInputStream();
                bmImg=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("Picture Error", e.toString());
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super .onPostExecute(result);
            ImageView image;
            LinearLayout piclayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.gallery_preview_scroll_layout);
            image = new ImageView(Gallery.this);
            image.setImageBitmap(bmImg);
            piclayout.addView(image);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Definitely not the best solution.